# I want to clear remaining form fields when i change a form value

Tags: php

I want to clear remaining form fields when i change a form value, i.e, when i change the shape of a product i want to clear remaining fields like size, quantity,options etc.Now only some fields are clearing

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: And can you explain a bit. Is it just a specific form input you are targeting or any of them. If you are targeting any of the form fields, you can never complete the form, isn't it?

Comment: `$('#productform')[0].reset();` Resets all fields

Comment: i had used  $('#total_product_price').val('');
  $('#per_product_cost').val('');
  $('#lbl_summary').html(''); ,all the fields are cleared but i cant clear dropdownlist with it

Comment: html code:
   <div class="tf">4. Select how many colors</div>  
   <div class="field" >
     <select class="drp" style="margin:4px 30px;" name="no_of_colors" id="no_of_colors" onChange="javascript:lamination('no_of_colors');" >
     <option value="0"></option><?php
          for($p=0;$p<6;$p++)
               {
       $r = $p+1;
                                       $amt = $r * $color_swap_cost;
   ?>    <option value="<?php echo $r; ?>"> <?php echo $r; ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>    
 </select> </div>